# Serialize Dictionaries with Object as Key in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project I am serialising the following Dictionary:

```
var stats = new Dictionary<Category, Int32> {
  { new Category { Id = 1, Name = "A" }, 1 }, 
  { new Category { Id = 2, Name = "B" }, 2 } 
};
```

However in my Json I get the following:

```
"stats": {
  "MyProj.Category": 1,
  "MyProjCategory": 2
},
```

How to serialize dictionaries?

Comment: How would you want this to be serialized considering that JSON only allows string keys?

Comment: That the key would be an object with Id and Name?

Comment: That is not valid in JSON. You can only have string keys.